# Get all columns using ExcelJS in a workbook

Tags: javascript, excel, exceljs

I am using ExcelJS to read in an xlsx file. I need to read all of the columns of the xlsx, but I can't find anything about this in the [documentation](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#columns)

I have something like this -

```
window.workbook = workbook;
const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Input");
const idCol = worksheet.getColumn(1);
const nameCol = worksheet.getColumn(2);
```

I need to be able to iterate through all of the columns and add them to an array. I cant even find how to get the number of total columns...

Comment: Have you looked at `columnCount` in the Worksheet Metrics section?